# Reshape matrix with an Excel function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What is a (simple) Excel worksheet function that reshapes a size mn column into a size mxn matrix so that the entry (n-1)j+i of the former is the entry (i,j) of the latter, for positive integers i<=m and j<=n? I am NOT asking for a VBA code.

Comment: Your use of the **$** symbol when (I believe) you should be using the back-tick (e.g. **`**) makes your question hard to interpret from its narrative alone. Can you edit your question to include sample data together with expected results?

Comment: @Jeeped: My $ symbols were intended as LaTeX format for mathematical symbols. It appears LaTeX format is not recognized here. I have changed it. How does one typeset mathematical symbols here?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single simple built-in worksheet function that does that, but you could do it with a series of n array-entered OFFSET functions in the columns.